# Change stylesheet attribute inside iframe using DOMDocument class

Tags: php, html

I'm using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)  class in order to change `link` tag attribute when the page is load.
The tag that I want to manipulate is inside iframe block, so my code doesn't take effect in that specific case.
Here's the code:

```
$page_content = file_get_contents($page_link);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml($page_content);


$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');

foreach( $links as $k => $link ){
    if( $link->getAttribute('rel') === 'stylesheet' ){
        $link->setAttribute('rel', 'test'); //just fot testing
    }
}

$newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();


echo $newHtml;
```

But only the main  tag is affected, while the `<link>` inside the iframe block don't:

```
<head>
       <link rel="test" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
.
    <iframe>
        <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/><!--"rel" stays the same-->
        </head>
    </iframe>
.
.
.
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: what is inside links do a var_dump()

Comment: Provide real `$page_link` value or do `echo htmlentities( $page_content ); die();` to see **real** `<iframe>` content.

Comment: the real page link is http://mida.org.il/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%96-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%91-2016/.. I echoed htmlentities and didn't see my the iframe...

Comment: Yup. This because there is not anything in it. The content is probably loaded by javascript (its id is “gform_ajax_frame_2”). So you **can not** modify its content with DOM.

Comment: Is there anyway to modify that iframe? My end goal is to put link to my style.css file in order to modify the css INSIDE the iframe..